# Tapestry 5 - Edit arraylist of Strings

Tags: java, arraylist, tapestry

I have a Result object (named result), and inside that object is an arraylist of strings (named action), as well as some other values.

I can make a text area to edit values of the Result object like this:

```
<input t:type="TextArea" t:id="feedback" t:value="result.someValue" />
```

This works fine. However, I would like to show a text field for each of the Strings in the ArrayList within the result object

I can create a loop like this:

```
<t:loop t:source="result.action" t:value="currentAction" index="indexProp" t:formstate="ITERATION">
   ${currentAction}
</t:loop>
```

This will show me on the screen all of the actions (that is great, half way there). However I want these to be editable using a TextField.

I have tried several things, none of which have worked how I wanted. However, to help explain and as an example of what I have tried, this is what I have:

```
<t:loop t:source="result.action" t:value="currentAction" index="indexProp" t:formstate="ITERATION">
<input t:type="TextField" t:value="result.action.indexProp"/>
</t:loop>
```

This won't work because (as far as I know), this is the same as getResult().getAction.getIndexProp. So I tried

```
<input t:type="TextField" t:value="result.action.${indexProp}"/>
```

This doesn't work either, although it shows the correct number of TextFields, it does not link them up properly (they just say inside them "result.action.0" and "result.action.1".

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
<input t:type="TextField" t:value="result.action[indexProp]"/>
```

Not sure if tapestry is smart enough to determine getters and setters for individual list elements... probably not.

If that doesn't work, you can add a getter/setter to your page so that tapestry can create an appropriate [PropBinding](http://tapestry.apache.org/5.3/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/internal/bindings/PropBinding.html)

Java

```
@Property
private int indexProp;

@Property
private SomeObject result;

public void setCurrentAction(String action) {
    result.actions.set(indexProp);
}

public String getCurrentAction() {
    return result.actions.get(indexProp);
}
```

TML

```
<t:loop t:source="result.action" t:index="indexProp" t:formstate="ITERATION">
    <input t:type="TextField" t:value="currentAction"/>
</t:loop>
```

Comment: Thanks Lance, I will give this a try. I also received a message from the Tapestry users mailing list which can be found here: http://apache-tapestry-mailing-list-archives.1045711.n5.nabble.com/Displaying-an-ArrayList-of-strings-in-a-form-using-TextFields-td5726867.html

I tried the first of these (Which you assumed probably wouldn't work) and got:  Could not convert 'result.action[indexProp]' into a component parameter binding: Error parsing property expression 'result.action[indexProp]': line 1:6 missing EOF at '.'. 

I'll try the second now, it looks like it should work.

Comment: This worked perfectly, although there is an interesting discussion that anyone viewing this after me should view which is on the link in the previous comment. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I claim the answer from the mailing list! :D

Comment: I think our answers are different. Note how I use a custom getter / setter and don't specify a `value` parameter for the `loop`

Answer (score 2):

Here's the most straightforward option:

```
<t:loop t:source="result.action" t:value="currentAction" formState="iteration"> 
    <input t:type="TextField" t:value="currentAction"/> 
</t:loop>
```

Use `formState="iteration"` so Loop will get the edited list from your code again, when the form submission is being handled. Of course, this list should be the exact same instance
used when you're rendering the form. The form submission is in a different
request from the page rendering, so you either need to get the list again
or `@Persist` the list or the object to which this list belongs. See the
JavaDoc for LoopFormState or more details.